# Migrate Ubuntu 16.04 between laptops (same model)

Tags: backup, migration

I would like to learn on how I can make a copy of system to be moved to another machine. My laptop started to fail at few things, most likely hardware issue, and I must send it to manufacturer's technical service. Before I do so, I'd like to make a copy of what I have in case they format/replace my disk or just send me a new piece of equipment. I will hold the backup on two external drives (just to make sure).

What I would like to "save":

- my home directory obviously (without .cache dir and one other)
- all installed packages and applications (compilers, parsers, utility apps, libraries, etc.)
- configuration for several things like local web server, PHP-FPM
- drivers, drivers, drivers, because last time I tried to make a fresh install, I had to use Ethernet cable because there was no drivers for my wireless card

I have few applications that were installed using .deb package, but these I can lose (NetBeans and QtFramework with QtCreator), the rest of them I'd like to keep.

I think it would be much easier to include whole /etc directory to deal with configurations, rather than selecting them one by one. Are there any other directories that may contain stuff like configs, settings?

Is there any reliable tool I could use for that? It may be command-line tool, I don't mind, as long as it allows me to specify what I want to include, exclude and that would generate a single file, most probably compressed - so simply copying won't work.

If it helps you, my home director
y is about 42GB, but I only need about 25-30% of that to be backed up.

## EDIT

Just thought I would also mention it in the question itself. It is fair to assume I will not move to another hardware configuration. This is only for the case where configuration is exactly the same. I'm not sure if that changes anything.

## EDIT 2

Alright, I figured out the way to backup my applications list using this "tutorial": https://gist.github.com/brpaz/6d5bbcb5231cae2132ff

Now I'm only looking for some nice GUI application that would let me to backup my home directory excluding few subdirectories. I would much more prefer if it created a compressed file instead of just copying files, but if there's nothing out there, I will take anything really :) Deja dup does not work for me (it does not exclude directories I want to exclude, no matter what I do). I want to emphasize the need to exclude certain directories (either by selecting them or using a pattern), because 70% of my home directory can be recreated other way (e.g. local git repositories).

Comment: I usually backed up the whole etc to have config backup. You may need sometimes to backup also some directories from var (/var/www/html/, var/named/chroot/etc/, ...). I would backup home directory with tar. You can use exclude options to name the directories , which you want to exclude from backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get clonezilla and make a drive backup image, or even clone the drive itself

http://clonezilla.org/

Comment: This would be one option, but what about excluding directories? Also I use separate partitions for home, var and root. I think I should have been more specific. I don't really want to store apps and libs and drivers on in my backup, I'd rather use some app/script that could generate the list of installed stuff and once I decide to restore my backups, I'd like to be able to use that list to automatically install everything. Of course in addition to copying the files I need (part of home dir)

Comment: clonezilla can do partition backup/clone also. copy apt's package list (I forget the directory). but another thread said if you put the list in a new install then apt will install everything that you had.

Comment: I think if you could tell me where I can find all files associated with apt (that would let me install them on fresh system) it would be a good start. I did check out clonezilla, but I think this is not something I neccessarily need. I would still need to clone two partitions (/etc dir is on one, /home is on another) and I only need about 30% of my /home directory (I have a lot of builds I don't need, huge local git repos I don't need).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cat` for creating full disk image.

Run from usb flash, do not mount your current hard drive, turn on you external drive and run from root something about it:

```
cat /dev/sda > /media/extHDD/path/to/image.img
```

where `/dev/sda` is your current hard drive.

To apply a backup, simply run afterwards:

```
cat /media/extHDD/path/to/image.img > /dev/sda
```

Comment: Thank you, but this answer does ignore the fact I only want some of the data (part of home directory + all directories that may contain any configs outside my home directory). My /var directory is twice as big as my home dir for example, but I don't need most of these things. Also instead of copying all apps and things installed with apt / dpkg, I think there should be a way to "list" all that, store in file and "restore" once I need it?

Comment: You can use some more specific clone/backup tools for this, however I don't believe that they could do exactly what you want. You'll definitely need to write a complex script for that, but it could take a lot of time and it probably can't be used again. I think it would be quicker and simpler just backup only you home dir and reinstall ubuntu or backup the whole disk drive.

Comment: I see, well, for now I managed to create squashfs files for /etc, /opt /var and /usr/local. Now I'm checking out deja dup to see if it works. The reason I would like to avoid making a copy of my /home dir is that 70% of that data includes git repositories, Qt and large binary files (a lot of C++ builds) that I do not really need in my backup. I tried excluding few dirs in deja dup, unfortunately as far as I can tell, they're scanned anyway. Let's see how it works out though.